# Unable to login to artifactory docker repository

Tags: authentication, ssl, docker, artifactory

I am using an nginx reverse proxy behind the artifactory server as decribed in this document https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Repositories

When I try and login to the repository I get the following error

```
Error response from daemon: no successful auth challenge for https://mynginxloadbalancer:2222/v2/ -
```

Note that I am using a certified CA certifacte (digicert) and can access the repository in the browser. I am on docker version 1.10 and artifactory version pro 4.2.2

Comment: Does your cert from Digicert contain the intermediary certificate?